# Какой API является RESTful?

Tags: api, rest

Главный вопрос: 
Считается ли API RESTful, если всё взаимодействие сводится к как минимум 4 операциям (POST, GET, DELETE, PUT)? 
Задаю такой вопрос не просто так, просто потому что вроде у REST в гугле описано 5-6 принципов каких стоит придерживаться, но вот если посмотреть некоторые туториалы, то всё обходится тем, что идет проверка каким методом был послан нам запрос и в зависимости от этого проделать какое то действие. Если PUT то изменить, POST добавить, GET получить, DELETE удалить. Также для своего фреймворка Yii2 глянул про работу с REST API, [тут тоже самое](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/), работа с разными методами запроса.
Меня это путает очень сильно всё, по скольку некоторые говорят что тема реста размыта, бери и работай просто. 
Как-то по мейлу написали "Есть ли опыт в работе с REST API?". Так почитав даже в гугле очень тяжело понять в какую степь двигаться, мне например нужно написать АПИ, а как я пойму - рестовое оно, или не рестовое?

Вопрос номер 2: если у меня есть сайт, и я хочу сделать приложение мобильное для него под iOS & Android, мне стоит сделать сначала API, а потом разрабатывая под определенную ОС работать как раз с моим написанным API этими методами POST, PUT, DELETE, GET? То есть при просмотре пользователя страницы будет /GET, отправке сообщения - /POST, удалении сообщения /DELETE? Примерно так работают всеми любимые социальные сети типо ВК на мобилках?
Буду благодарен за ответы, это очень важные вопросы для меня

Comment: Нет, у ВК вообще не REST

Comment: стоит удалить второй вопрос, причины: должен быть один и он оффтоп, ответ на второй вопрос может быть основан на мнении и не может быть объективным

Answer (score 1):

> Главный вопрос: Считается ли API RESTful, если всё взаимодействие
>   сводится к как минимум 4 операциям (POST, GET, DELETE, PUT)?

Я бы перефразировал данный вопрос таким образом:

> Главный вопрос: Считается ли API **100%-о** RESTful, если всё
>   взаимодействие сводится к как минимум 4 операциям (POST, GET, DELETE,
>   PUT)?

И на него бы ответил, нет, этого недостаточно, помимо использования этих методов также необходимо придерживаться других определённых правил игры, подробнее [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181988/)

> Вопрос номер 2: если у меня есть сайт, и я хочу сделать приложение
>   мобильное для него под iOS & Android, мне стоит сделать сначала API, а
>   потом разрабатывая под определенную ОС работать как раз с моим
>   написанным API этими методами POST, PUT, DELETE, GET? То есть при
>   просмотре пользователя страницы будет /GET, отправке сообщения -
>   /POST, удалении сообщения /DELETE?

Здесь же в самом вопросе даёте ответ на оный.

Comment: спасибо за статью) а про второй вопрос, так мысль правильная? сначала пишем апи, а потом работаем с этим апи, и с него рождается мобильное приложение для сайта? и вот у вк апи например поддерживает только get и post, это уже автоматом не рест считается? а визуально понять рест можно по понятным запросам типа DELETE /dogs/42 - удалить собаку с id 42? Я слышал что рест должен быть понятен визуально

Comment: @idriverx да, мысль правильная, а что касается вк, там json api, подробнее здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/265845/

Comment: На хабр лучше не ссылаться, там обычно доминируют разрозненные знания с додумками автора, и эта статья, к сожалению, не исключение.